# Is this sed command valid?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have 2 lines of sed that I have trouble understanding

I understand that the syntax of sed is :

> sed OPTIONS [SCRIPT] [INPUTFILE]

but in this command below there is no input file I am just curious what this is doing, any help is very much appreciated

1.

```
$(echo $d | sed 's/.*\///g')#
```

2. 

```
cat /kaldi/README | sed "s/akiplaner/${n}/g" >  extracted/$nf/etc/README #
```

---

*note : below is the whole code

```
for d in /dir1/dataset/audios/*; do
    echo $d
    n=$(echo $d | sed 's/.*\///g') #
    nf=${n}
    echo $n $a $nf
    mkdir -p extracted/$nf/wav
    mkdir -p extracted/$nf/etc
    rm -f extracted/$nf/etc/prompts-original
    rm -f extracted/$nf/etc/PROMPTS
    cat /kaldi/README | sed "s/akiplaner/${n}/g" >extracted/$nf/etc/README #

    for f in $d/*.wav; do
        n2=$(echo $f | sed 's/.*\///g')
        n3=$(echo $n2 | sed 's/\.wav//g') # removing .wav from $n2 string
        echo $n2
        echo $n3
        cp $f extracted/$nf/wav/$n2
        #sox --vol 0.01 $f -t wav extracted/$nf/wav/$n2;
        normalize-audio -a 0.3 extracted/$nf/wav/$n2

        cp $d/$n3.txt temp.txt

        echo "$n3 $(cat temp.txt)" >>extracted/$nf/etc/prompts-original
        echo "${nf}/mfc/${n3} $(cat temp.txt)" >>extracted/$nf/etc/PROMPTS
    done
    a=$(($a + 1))
done
```

Comment: the [manual](https://man.cx/sed(1)) says "if no input files are specified, then the standard input is read".

Comment: what is the standard input here?

Comment: I was trying figure out the pattern here,  's/.*\///g'  am I correct in saying this pattern is removing any file or folder whose name starts with / so basically removing all the foldername and leaving only the last foldername e.g., for L1/L2/L3 this will only leave L3

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but use `n=${d##*/}` instead of `n=$(echo $d | sed 's/.*\///g')`. The latter is overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: You have some fundamental issues in your code. Copy paste it and any other shell script you write into http://shellcheck.net (as instructed by the ]bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag you used) and fix the issues the tool tells you about before posting any questions.

Comment: Something shellcheck can't warn you about - `echo "$n3 $(cat temp.txt)" > foo` will fail in cryptic ways if temp.txt contains anything the shell can expand, e.g. "$HOME" and (depending on your echo version) the contents of `n3` contains escape sequences. `{ printf '%s\n' "$n3"; cat temp.txt; } > foo` will be more robust and portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no input file I am just curious what this is doing

The answer is at your fingertips.

```
$ LC_ALL=C sed --help
...
... if no input files are
specified, then the standard input is read.
```

Note: `|` shell operator connects one command standard output to another command's standard input. There are surely endless resources on the internet for basic introduction to shell streams and input output operations - it might be a good occasion to research some of them, like https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput .

> ```
> sed OPTIONS [SCRIPT] [INPUTFILE]
> ```

It's:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sed --help
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...
```

The stuff in `[...]` is *optional*. `...` represents stuff it can be repeated.

---

There are man problems with the script - it will break on filenames with spaces or newlines in the name or on filenames with `*` in the name... Remember to check your scripts with shellcheck - it will catch such mistakes.

> 's/.*///g' am I correct in saying this pattern is removing any file or folder whose name starts with

From a *line* of text it removes everything `.*` before a `/` slash. You can learn regex with fun with https://regexcrossword.com/ and sed here https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html .

It's an odd way of writing `basename "$n"` and the next line is just `basename "$n" .wav`.